# How to turn a Python + Glade3 project into .exe format?

Tags: python, type-conversion, executable, glade

I'm not that good at programming and I'd like some help. I made a Python/Glade project, I think I have Glade 3.6.7 installed and Python 2.6.5. I'd like to turn it into a .exe file. Instead of putting my entire program, I think that if I could figure out how to turn this program (the two links have the two parts of a simple program) into an .exe, I'll manage to do the same on my own. I followed this tutorial for a lot of the parts of my program so I'd assume it would translate well.
http://gnipsel.com/glade/glade04.html

http://gnipsel.com/glade/python04.html

I made a new question (and an account actually) since the answers that I found weren't really relevant for what I'm doing.

Thank you very much, I appreciate your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use  http://www.py2exe.org/.

Think of making a python executable as giving your user a minimmal python distro, that will open and 'execute' your *.py files.

Comment: I tried using py2exe, I ended up on this guide http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK. It seems to convert fine but my program doesn't work. In the error log it always gives this error:   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "gtk\glade.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gtk\glade.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong? Or alternate solutions?